# Aggregation with OR filter

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an index of jBPM usertasks. Each usertask has `id`, `actualOwner` and `actualOwner.keyword`, `potentialOwners` and `potentialOwners.keyword`, and `processId` fields.

I need this aggregation: count of usertasks per process for some user. User task belongs to user if it's `actualOwner` or `potentialOwner` is that user. And in some statuses.

Seems that is very easy query, but I cannot write it. I try this:

```
POST jbpm-tasks/_search?size=1000
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        { 
          "term": {
            "actualOwner.keyword": {
              "value": "vasya"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "potentialOwners.keyword": {
              "value": "vasya"
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "must": [
        {
          "terms": {
            "status.keyword": [
              "Created",
              "Reserved",
              "InProgress",
              "Ready"
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "byProcesses": {
      "terms": { "field": "processId.keyword", "size": 1000000 } 
    }
  }
}
```

Query as I understand does not filter, it calculate score only. So, for this query really not matter user login, for `vasya` and. for example, `fedya` request returns same aggregation results (with different scores for tasks, but it is not interesting for now).

I not understand how write filter aggregation for multiple filter with `OR` and `AND` formula. In all examples always one field...

How to write this query properly?

Comment: Hmmm, seems minimum_should_match=1 option did the trick. If you see how write this query more correct, please write it here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't need to sort your data by score of relevancy, it would be better to use `filter`. Besides, if you just need to use data from aggregation part, it is wise to set `size:0` to make elasticsearch to not to return any posts, and just return the aggs result. in my view the below query can have better performance for you:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "terms": {
            "status.keyword": [
              "Created",
              "Reserved",
              "InProgress",
              "Ready"
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "should": [
              {
                "term": {
                  "actualOwner.keyword": {
                    "value": "vasya"
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "term": {
                  "potentialOwners.keyword": {
                    "value": "vasya"
                  }
                }
              }
            ],
            "minimum_should_match": 1
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "byProcesses": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "processId.keyword",
        "size": 1000000
      }
    }
  }
```

Overall, setting large number into size of aggregations makes it very heavy. If you want to go through all your data comes from aggregations, it would be a good option if you use composite aggregations [link](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/search-aggregations-bucket-composite-aggregation.html).

Answer (score 0):

Which version do you use? Different versions have different grammar.

You are right in comment, `minimum_should_match=1` is the way.
If the bool query includes no must or filter clauses, the default `minimum_should_match` value is 1, the query behaves like you originally understood.

Otherwise, the default `minimum_should_match` value is 0, which makes `should` clauses different from `OR`, `should` clauses doesn't filter any document.

```json
POST jbpm-tasks/_search?size=1000
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        { 
          "term": {
            "actualOwner.keyword": {
              "value": "vasya"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "potentialOwners.keyword": {
              "value": "vasya"
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "must": [
        {
          "terms": {
            "status.keyword": [
              "Created",
              "Reserved",
              "InProgress",
              "Ready"
            ]
          }
        },
      ],
      "minimum_should_match" : 1
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "byProcesses": {
      "terms": { "field": "processId.keyword", "size": 1000000 } 
    }
  }
}
```